# Правильно ли мой друг использовал точку с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, точка-с-запятой

[image: Явно не правильно]

Мой друг использовал точку с запятой, но правильно ли? Мне кажется, что нет.

Answer (score 2):

Неправильно. Точка с запятой используется в других случаях. В сложноподчиненном предложении с придаточным условием применяется запятая: «Коли (если) вам надоело ждать, то...»

К тому же в этом ответе полно других ошибок.

Comment: Слову "коли" соответствует "раз" (то же самое) и "если **уж**" (не просто "если", с ним одним условие получается, а не факт).

Comment: Процитирую ЯКласс (9 класс, русский язык): «Придаточные условия прикрепляются к главному предложению союзами: если, коли, когда (в значении «если»), раз (в значении «если»), кабы, ежели, будет, ли... ли, как (в значении «если»)».

Comment: Разница есть, они похожи, но и близко не равны. Возьмём такие примеры: *Раз это дорого, сходи в другой магазин. Если это дорого, сходи в другой магазин.* Вы улавливаете разницу? В первом случае известно, что это дорого для него, а во втором нет.